# Expected distance between leaf nodes in a binary tree

Tags: probability, independence, trees, expected-value

> Let T be a full binary tree with $8$ leaves. (A full binary tree has every level full). Suppose that two leaves a and b of T are chosen uniformly and independently at random. The expected value of the distance between a and b in T (i.e number of edges in the unique path between a and b) is ?

---

#### My Attempt:

This question is really simple. The only thing I want to confirm is whether the answer to this question will be $4.86$ or $4.25$ ?
As per me the answer should be $4.86$. I solved it this way:
sum of distances from a particular leaf to the remaining $7$ leaves is $34$.
The sum would remain the same for each leaf node. Therefore total sum of distance of all the leaf nodes $= 34\times8$.
So, expectation $= (34 \times 8)/(8 \times 7) = 4.86$.

> Am I correct with the answer?

Comment: Your are unfair in calculating total path length (i.e. 34*8, means you assumed that all 8 leaf nodes has distance), then why are not counting as total number of ways (i.e., 8*8 instead of 8*7)? So, $$\frac{(34 \times 8)}{(8 \times 8)} = 4.25$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer assumes that once $a$ is chosen, there are $7$ possibilities for the $b$, at an average distance of $34/7$ (and this value doesn't depend on $a$). But this ignores the possibility that $a$ and $b$ are equal (distance $0$); since they are chosen independently this can happen, and so in fact there are $8$ possibilities for $b$ at an average distance of $34/8$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Two leaf nodes can be selected in $8\times8 = 64$ ways.