# Expected value of unique path between a and b

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let T be a full binary tree with 8 leaves. (A full binary tree has every level full). Suppose that two leaves a and b of T are chosen uniformly and independently at random. The expected value of the distance between a and b in T (i.e number of edges in the unique path between a and b) is ?

My analysis:-
The answer should be 4.86 assuming that I do not consider a case wherein two leaf nodes chosen is actually the same leaf node because I assumed that any two nodes are selected together and not in order that is one after other. I do not understand the point of linking independence with choosing the same node twice. I do understand that if we assume two nodes are chosen in order then for independence we do need to necessarily consider the paths of the length 0 but the question mentions nothing about the order and choosing two leaf nodes.

**Note that this question has already been answered in a previous post [Link of the Post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114447/expected-distance-between-leaf-nodes-in-a-binary-tree) but all the answers mentioned assume that for independence it is necessary to involve a condition wherein two leaf nodes can infact be the same node ie distance 0 node. My point is if we do not choose two leaf nodes in order ie. One after another and rather think of it as two leaf nodes are chosen together then why do we need to include the condition wherein two nodes can be same.**

Comment: If two nodes are chosen uniformly and independently, then the two nodes can be the same.  This is not an assumption; it's what the condition means.  What you are talking about is a *pair* of nodes being chosen uniformly at random.  There's no question of independence, because there's only one event.

Comment: @saulspatz So you mean that here we cannot consider the scenario wherein a pair of nodes are chosen together because had it been so there would never be a scenario of independence between them because they are basically events on same stage ?

Comment: No, not at all.  It's just a question of terminology.  As I said, you should describe the scenario you want by saying "A pair of nodes is chosen uniformly at random from a full binary tree ..."  That means each pair of nodes has an equal chance of being selected.

Comment: Well then can we  say for assuming two nodes to be actually the same node, the question should have been worded as "two leaves a and b of T are chosen 
 **one after another** uniformly and independently at random" . I do not understand that why is it so obvious to consider it as a case where two nodes are chosen one after another when the question just say two nodes are chosen?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of independence?  If selecting node A the first time rules out selecting node A the second time, how can it be that the two events are independent?  The problem description is unambiguous and common.  You just have to accept that it means what it means.

Comment: Apparently, I was wrong.  Other people accept your interpretation.  See the comments at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121515/independently-and-uniformly-selected-numbers

Comment: @saulspatz Thankyou! So can it be said as an ambiguous question?

Comment: Well, I still don't think do, but other people do.